# Apache RAM usage doubled

Tags: apache, ubuntu

I'm using nodequery to monitor my server ( 2GB Ram ) my server is primarily hosting several wordpress websites. and the RAM usage is about 1GB-1,2GB ,

but i don't know why, since April 16th the daily average RAM usage is doubled to about 2GB.

the effect is that now my website is often down. which again i don't know but when i restart apache the website is up again and the RAM usage is down to about 600MB, but after few hours it back to 2GB and then my websites down again.

How can i know what cause this ? the other metric like cpu usage,network usage is normal

i tried quick solution like restart apache every few hours with cron but i cant make it work.

Details : Ubuntu 16.04 RAM 2GB 2 core Apache 2.4.18

Thank you for your help

Comment: did you activated some extra modules after you first install apache? because these could be the reason. Also, [read this](https://serverfault.com/a/112365).

Comment: another solution might be [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/187308/285162)

Comment: @BinarWeb thank you , i will try that